# How to give user wise numbers to uploaded videos which is to be displayed on Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Model

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class VideoUploads(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    video = models.FileField(null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Videos'
```

I am getting Output as shown in the image attached
  [image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP7Wl.jpg]

I want something like this

```
bbbb Videos 2
aaaa Videos 2
bbbb Videos 1
aaaa Videos 1
```

As I keep adding videos the number of the videos uploaded should be displayed next to it.

I used **repr**() method also but as we know it displays only Object name but not the content.

Please help me out with this

Comment: Your model says that video is a FileField, which means that FileUpload may contain only one file. Could you explain when do you expect to see `bbbb Videos 2`?

Comment: user bbbb can upload videos in different intervals, say if he uploads the 1st video today and he can upload the second video tomorrow, so bbbb's first video should be named as "bbbb videos 1"  and  the video bbbb uploads tomorrow should be named as "bbbb videos 2" , pls refer the image where aaaa uploaded 2 videos and bbbb uploaded 2 videos but in different intervals

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you should be doing it in `User` admin, not in `VideoUploads` admin because one video upload is one file and you want a summary for users. To get upload count for a user you can call `user.videouploads_set.count()`

Comment: perfect, Thanks  Karolis Ryselis